# Difference between XQuery and DOM

Tags: xml, xquery, jdom

What is the difference between XQuery and JDOM parser? Both are using for processing XML documents. Which is more efficient?

Comment: Without use case, "Which is more eficient?" is not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to process XML documents : SAX, StAX, DOM, XQuery, XSLT... DOM uses a tree like structure you can navigate, and XQuery uses a query language. DOM not only let you process existing XML documents, but also let you generate new documents, while XQuyery is probably more efficient for retrieving complex data from a large XML document using the powerful query language.